# Javascript - Comparison: 20 more than

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators

I want to know if is possible in JavaScript to have comparisons such as this:

> If (a is 20 more than b) {code code code}

I know you can use the greater than (`>`) or less than (`<`) symbols for comparisons similar to this, but I need to say if something is within 20 more than something. How would you do this?

Comment: The comparison operators can’t do that, but arithmetic can: `if (a === b + 20)`

Comment: you're looking for the difference, right?  `if ((a-b) > 20) { ... }`  seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: Humble question indeed, but I don't think it deserves to be punished for that.

Answer (score 0):

Any expression can appear on either side of the comparison, for example:

```
if (a >= b + 20) {
    // code code code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't that something like this ?

```
if ((a + 20) > b) {
    code...
}
```

Comment: That would work but to the way I can explained it... but what I meant was: if (a is within 20 more than b) {code}. would that be possible?